# Edge browser options ignored on Linux Docker container running as Selenium Grid

Tags: linux, docker, microsoft-edge, selenium-grid

When running automated tests written in Robot Framework locally on Windows, it works for Chrome/Edge. Basically browser options e.g. headless are taken into consideration.
If it is running on Selenium Grid (as a docker container with Linux OS) the browser option arguments are only taken for Chrome node. The browser Edge starts as it would be without any set parameter.

Here is the code excerpt for particular browsers:

```
Launch Browser
[Documentation]  Opens desired browser type.
Run keyword if  '${BROWSER}'=='edge'
...  Run Edge
...  ELSE
...  Run Chrome
Maximize browser window

Run Edge
[Documentation]  Set configuration and open Edge browser.
${EDGE_OPTIONS}  Catenate  SEPARATOR=
...  use_chromium=True;add_argument("--headless=true");
...  add_argument("--no-sandbox");add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"]);
...  add_argument("--proxy-server\=http://myproxy.domain.com:8080")
Open Browser  about:blank  browser=${BROWSER}  options=${EDGE_OPTIONS}  remote_url=${SELENIUM_GRID_HUB_URL}

Run Chrome
[Documentation]  Set configuration and open Chrome browser
${CHROME_OPTIONS}  Catenate  SEPARATOR=
...  add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"]);add_argument("--headless=true");
...  add_argument("--proxy-server\=http://myproxy.domain.com:8080")
Open Browser  about:blank   browser=${BROWSER}  options=${CHROME_OPTIONS}  remote_url=${SELENIUM_GRID_HUB_URL}
```

Any suggestion why the browser options are ignored for Edge on Linux Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

On our project we experienced the same issues. Our project is written with Selenium 3.141.59. Our project is java based and to enable the use of MS Edge Chromium we had to add a new service provided by Microsoft, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=java#customize-the-microsoft-edge-driver-service).

We added that service to our EdgeDriverFactory and we were able to test with local Edge Chromium browser. However, when constructing RemoteWebDriver to be used with our selenium grid it had issues when we tried to construct it with the Edge Driver Service

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL, com.microsoft.edge.seleniumtools.EdgeDriverService)'
```

As per you experience without being able to add the service constructor, the Edge browser would start but without any of the set parameters (options), even with Selenium Grid v4.

We have migrated our project to Selenium 4.0.0 as a POC, so far we have had no issues testing with Edge Chromium browser via Selenium Grid v4 (we use the official docker based hub and node, provided by Selenium).

The Edge Chromium browser starts with all the parameters in place with no issues, just as when we test the local browser.

Comment: We run on Selenium Grid v4.
When checking versions (pip list) of packages.
msedge-selenium-tools                   3.141.3
selenium                                4.0.0rc1
Not sure what else to do to solve it.

Comment: From a java perspective, we had `com.microsoft.edge.seleniumtools`, which included: EdgeDriverService, EdgeOptions and EdgeDriver. None of these worked with selenium grid v3 or v4 via the official selenium docker images. So for us to test with official selenium grid using their docker images, we had to move to selenium v4.0.0 and use `org.openqa.selenium.edge` for EdgeOptions and EdgeDriver. For all the other browsers, we are able to keep their related projects (if Edge browser is not tested) on selenium v3.141.59. All our projects use official docker images for our selenium grid solutions.